# Aggrerate nested objectid

Tags: mongodb

I have documents like this:

```
    {
       "_id": "...",
       "collectionName": "blabla",
       "items": ["ObjectID("1")","ObjectID("2")"],
    }
```

items collection:

```
{
   "_id": "1",
   "name": "item name",
   "size": 3
},
{
   "_id": "2"
   "name": "item name 2",
    "size": 4
}
```

Output:

```
{
   "_id": "...",
   "collectionName": "blabla",
   "items": ["ObjectID("1")","ObjectID("2")"],
   "totalSize": 7
}
```

I'm trying to use aggrerate to sum all items size which is referenced by ObjectID

is this even possible? I couldn't find any information about it

Comment: Please provide your expected result and a dummy data

Comment: Are you looking for how many times item1 is present across all documents by id?

Comment: i have edited the question to make it more clear